# Binary Search Tree and finding the height of it using a recursive method

Tags: c#

I need to add a recursive method that is public, calls a private. It needs to find the height of the tree. From what I know an empty tree returns -1. With this information I need to find the height of the tree. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
public class BinSearchTree<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    private class Node  // shown in class
    {
        public T Data { get; set; }
        public Node Left;// { get; set; }
        public Node Right; // { get; set; }
        public Node(T d = default(T), Node leftnode = null, Node rightnode = null)
        {
            Data = d;
            Left = leftnode;
            Right = rightnode;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Data.ToString();
        }
    }

    private Node root;
    
    public BinSearchTree()
    {
        root = null;
    }
    public virtual void Clear()
    {
        root = null;
    }

    public T FindMinNR()
    {
        if (root == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("Can find min on empty tree");
        else
        {
            Node pTmp = root;
            while (pTmp.Left != null)
                pTmp = pTmp.Left;
            return pTmp.Data;
        }
    }
    public T FindMin()
    {
        if (root == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("FindMin called on empty BinSearchTree");
        else
            return FindMin(root);
    }
    private T FindMin(Node pTmp)
    {
        if (pTmp.Left == null)
            return pTmp.Data;
        else
            return FindMin(pTmp.Left);
    }

    public T Find(T value)
    {
        return Find(value, root);
    }
    private T Find(T value, Node pTmp)
    {
        if (pTmp == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("BinSearchTree could not find " + value);   // Item not found
        else if (value.CompareTo(pTmp.Data) < 0) // value < pTmp.Data
            return Find(value, pTmp.Left);      // search left subtree
        else if (value.CompareTo(pTmp.Data) > 0) // value > pTmp.Data
            return Find(value, pTmp.Right);     // search right subtree
        else
            return pTmp.Data;               // Found it
    }

    public bool TryFind(ref T value)
    {
        Node pTmp = root;
        int result;
        while (pTmp != null)
        {
            result = value.CompareTo(pTmp.Data);
            if (result == 0)
            {           // found it
                value = pTmp.Data;
                return true;
            }
            else if (result < 0)        // value < pTmp.Data, search left subtree
                pTmp = pTmp.Left;
            else if (result > 0)        // value > pTmp.Data, search right subtree
                pTmp = pTmp.Right;
        }
        return false;       // didn't find it
    }
    
    public void Insert(T newItem)
    {
        root = Insert(newItem, root);
    }
    private Node Insert(T newItem, Node pTmp)
    {
        if (pTmp == null)
            return new Node(newItem, null, null);
        else if (newItem.CompareTo(pTmp.Data) < 0) // newItem < pTmp.Data
            pTmp.Left = Insert(newItem, pTmp.Left);
        else if (newItem.CompareTo(pTmp.Data) > 0) // newItem > pTmp.Data 
            pTmp.Right = Insert(newItem, pTmp.Right);
        else   // Duplicate
            throw new ApplicationException("Tree did not insert " + newItem + " since an item with that value is already in the tree");

        return pTmp;
    }

    public void Remove(T value)
    {
        Remove(value, ref root);
    }
    private void Remove(T value, ref Node pTmp)
    {
        if (pTmp == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("BinSearchTree could not remove " + value);   // Item not found
        else if (value.CompareTo(pTmp.Data) < 0) // value < pTmp.Data
            Remove(value, ref pTmp.Left);
        else if (value.CompareTo(pTmp.Data) > 0) // value > pTmp.Data
            Remove(value, ref pTmp.Right);
        else if (pTmp.Left != null && pTmp.Right != null) // Two children
        {
            pTmp.Data = FindMin(pTmp.Right);
            Remove(pTmp.Data, ref pTmp.Right);
        }
        else
            pTmp = (pTmp.Left != null) ? pTmp.Left : pTmp.Right;
    }
    
    
    public bool TryInsert(T value)
    {
        if (root == null)
            root = new Node(value, null, null);
        else
        {
            Node pTmp = root, parent;
            while (pTmp != null)
            {
                parent = pTmp;
                if (value.CompareTo(pTmp.Data) == 0)        // trying to insert duplicate key
                    return false;
                else if (value.CompareTo(pTmp.Data) < 0)        // value < pTmp.Data, search left subtree
                {
                    pTmp = pTmp.Left;
                    if (pTmp == null)
                        parent.Left = new Node(value, null, null);
                }
                else         // value > pTmp.Data, search right subtree
                {
                    pTmp = pTmp.Right;
                    if (pTmp == null)
                        parent.Right = new Node(value, null, null);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public bool Contains(T value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("BST Contains not implemented");
    }

    public T FindMax()
    {
        return FindMax(root).Data;
    }
    private Node FindMax(Node pTmp)
    {
        if (pTmp == null)
            throw new ApplicationException("FindMax called on empty BinSearchTree");
        if (pTmp.Right == null)
            return pTmp;
        return FindMax(pTmp.Right);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work in your code?

Comment: And what code have you written so far towards your question?

Comment: @Cid I need to add a recursive method that is public, calls a private. It needs to find the height of the tree. I need to write a method but don't know how.

Comment: @Mode77 . I need to write a method but don't know how to do so as a recursive method. The code for binary search tree is up above.